# Can an optional parameter be optionally required in C#?

Tags: c#

Is there a possibility in C# to have an optional parameter be optionally required in specific situations and have it throw an error on **compile time**?

Let me explain with the code below as an example. The class `ServiceResponse` has a constructor accepting an enumeration value and an optional string. In case the enumeration value used to instantiate the class equals `Error`, the message becomes required. In the example code it will throw an `ArgumentNullException` when no message was supplied. Sadly this will only become visible on **run time**. However it should become visible on **compile time** so it warns the developer.

```cs
public class ServiceResponse
{
    public ServiceResponse(ServiceResult result, string message = null)
    {
        Result = result;
        Message = result == ServiceResult.Error ? message ?? throw new System.ArgumentNullException(nameof(message)) : message;
    }

    public string Message { get; }
    public ServiceResult Result { get; }
}

public enum ServiceResult {
    Ok,
    NotFound,
    Error
}
```

Comment: No. You could write a Roslyn analyzer which checks for this case. It might be easier to remove the enum from the interface, and use the static factory methods `ServiceResponse.Error(string message)`, `ServiceResponse.NotFound(string message = null)` and `ServiceResponse.Ok(string message = null)`

Comment: Suppose I have `new ServiceResponse(RandomServiceResult())`. Surely you would want an exception to be thrown if the random result returned by `RandomServiceResult` happens to be `ServiceResult.Error`?

Comment: There's still no way to *guarantee* that a passed string value isn't null without a runtime check.

Comment: @Sweeper you and Damien are both right, I realized that myself around the time you commented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would make the constructor private and expose the 3 static methods required to instantiate.

You can also make the `message` field in `CreateError(message)` as NotNull, and some linters will pick this up and treat as a warning.

```cs
public class ServiceResponse
{
    // Change constructor to private
    private ServiceResponse(ServiceResult result, string message)
    {
        Result = result;
        Message = message;
    }

    public static ServiceResponse CreateOk(string message = null)
    {
        return new ServiceResponse(ServiceResult.OK, message);
    }

    public static ServiceResponse CreateNotFound(string message = null)
    {
        return new ServiceResponse(ServiceResult.NotFound, message);
    }

    public static ServiceResponse CreateError([NotNull] string message)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(message))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(message));
        }

        return new ServiceResponse(ServiceResult.Error, message);
    }

    ... Other Class Properties
}
```

Comment: Ended up using @James his answer because it looks the cleanest and best solution to me and it also has the null check for the on runtime situation.

Answer (score 1):

Would static creation methods be an option?

```cs
public class ServiceResponse
{
    private ServiceResponse(ServiceResult result, string message = null)
    {
        Result = result;
        Message = message;
    }

    public string Message { get; }
    public ServiceResult Result { get; }

    public static ServiceResponse CreateInfo(ServiceResult result, string message = null)
    {
        return new ServiceResponse(result, message);
    }

    public static ServiceResponse CreateError(string message)
    {
        return new ServiceResponse(ServiceResult.Error, message);
    }
}
```

This doesn't prevent passing null to `CreateError`, but the developer probaly won't miss the message by accident.

Comment: Of course, even with nullable reference types that `string` passed to `CreateError` might still be `null`.

Comment: Surely you don't want `CreateError` to *also* take a `ServiceResult`?

Answer (score 1):

The [OneOf](https://github.com/mcintyre321/OneOf) library might be able to help here.

```
public abstract class ServiceResponse
    : OneOfBase<
        ServiceResponse.OkResult,
        ServiceResponse.NotFoundResult,
        ServiceResponse.ErrorResult>
{
    public class OkResult : ServiceResponse
    {
    }

    public class NotFoundResult : ServiceResponse
    {    
    }

    public class ErrorResult : ServiceResponse
    {
        public string Message { get; }
    }
}
```

Usage A

```
ServiceResponse result = ...;
if (result is ServiceResponse.OkResult ok)
   ...;
else if(result is ServiceResponse.ErrorResult error)
   ...;
```

Usage B

```
ServiceResponse result = ...;
result.Match( 
   ok => ...,
   notFound => ...,
   error => ...);
```

Comment: That looks like an interesting library and will take a closer look at it.

Comment: @Thrasher [Here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/421834/366320) you can find some guidance how can you use this library in a WebApi project.

Answer (score 0):

You have enum with types there. Take it and change it into specific objects with same interface(base class)

```
public abstract class ServiceResponse
{
    public ServiceResponse(ServiceResult result, string message = null)
    {
        Result = result;
        Message = result == ServiceResult.Error ? message ?? throw new System.ArgumentNullException(nameof(message)) : message; //questionable logic
    }

    public string Message { get; }
    public ServiceResult Result { get; }
}

public class OkServiceResponse : ServiceResponse
{
    public OkServiceResponse():base(ServiceResult.Ok){}
}

public class NotFoundServiceResponse : ServiceResponse
{
    public NotFoundServiceResponse(string message):base(ServiceResult.NotFound, message){}
}

public class ErrorServiceResponse : ServiceResponse
{
    public ErrorServiceResponse(string message):base(ServiceResult.Error, message){}
}
```

Comment: Result could be abstract in base and then overridden in each subtype, instead of put in constructor but its not that important